# Relative path to Entity in getRepository()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

It's a bit tedious writing the whole path to the Entity when calling `getRepository()`. Especially in Symfony2 where it would be `Acme\FooBundle\BarEntity`. Is it possible to make it so you only have to specify the Entity name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding a static method to my entities like this:

```
public static function getEntityName()
{
  return get_called_class();
}
```

then

```
use Acme\FooBundle\BarEntity;

$repo = $em->getRepository(BarEntity::getEntityName());
```

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for but clearly the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can write `->getRepository('FooBundle:BarEntity')`

Comment: That doesn't work for me. And it's still tedious and not DRY.

Comment: In S2 your entities should live in the Entity directory under the bundle.  Acme\FooBundle\Entity\Bar in which case FooBundle:Bar will work.  Not sure how you could improve a whole lot on BundleName:EntityName.  Suppose you could define some constants somewhere.

Comment: That's the setup I currently have and I get "Unknown Entity namespace alias".